# Random subsetting a data frame from a larger dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, random

```py
n = 100 # (n=height * width)
height = 10
width = 10
column = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
indices = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Rack2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(np.arange(n),size=(height, width), replace=False), index=list(indices), columns=list(column))
Rack = Rack2.sort_index(ascending=False)
a = np.repeat([True,False], Rack.size//2) 
b = np.random.shuffle(a)
a = a.reshape(Rack.shape)

SI = Rack.mask(a)
RI = Rack.where(a)

StorageSet = SI.stack() 
ss=dfStorage.index

RetrievalSet = RI.stack() 
tt=D3.index
```

In the python code above, there is a 10x10 Rack. Half of the rack (50 items) consists of storage items and the other half consists of retrieval items.

I want to do it not half of the rack size but if I have a 10x10 rack for example 30 of that data frame are storage items. 30 of the remaining 70 items are the retrieval items. How can I do this?

Comment: `a = np.hstack([np.repeat(True, 30), np.repeat(False, 70)])`?

Comment: This works but number of the storage and retrieval items must be equal. But in this solution number of storage items is 30 and number of retrieval items is 70

Comment: a = np.hstack([np.repeat(True, 30), np.repeat(False, 30)]) is the wanted solution. Is it possible?

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Misread the last part of the question.

Comment: Then, for this example 40 many values of the dataframe are not used. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you changed a couple of the variable names at the end of your code. `StorageSet` vs `dfStorage` and `RetrievalSet` vs `D3`.

Comment: Yes that's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a couple revisions to the code. First change the initialization of `a`:

```
samp_size = 30
a = np.hstack([np.repeat(0, samp_size), np.repeat(1, samp_size), np.repeat(np.nan, n - (2 * samp_size)])
```

Then you can get `SI` and `RI` as:

```
SI = Rack.where(a==0)
RI = Rack.where(a==1)
```

The rest of your code should work the same.